# Добавить ссылку на страницу предлагаемой правки описания метки в сообщение, показываемое после правки

Tags: предложение, описание-метки, предлагаемые-правки

После того, как предлагаю правку описания метки, на странице описания вижу следующий блок:

> **Спасибо за правку!**
>   Эта правка будет видна только вам до тех пор, пока она не пройдет экспертную проверку.

Он почти полностью идентичен такому же блоку, который виден после предлагаемой правки вопроса или ответа — с тем отличием, что на вопросе или ответе слова «экспертную проверку» являются ссылкой на страницу предлагаемой правки.

Хотелось бы, чтобы точно такое же было и после правки метки:

> **Спасибо за правку!**
>   Эта правка будет видна только вам до тех пор, пока она не пройдет [экспертную проверку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/141).

Есть небольшая сложность. В описании метки могут быть одновременно две правки — краткой и полной. В таком случае хотелось бы видеть две ссылки в любой форме.

Comment: Отличное предложение! Добавил в базу дефектов.

Comment: Это видимо давно поправлено? [Попробовал проверить](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49163439#49163439) - показывается ссылка.